# Find the number of rearrangements of the string 12345 in which none of the sequences 12, 23, 34, 45, and 51 occur.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

So I posted a [similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2376341) before, so please don't try to close this problem. Anyway I think I did this problem correctly, but I just want to make sure if I'm understanding what this question is asking me solve. So below I have my attempt at this problem:

> Let $A_{12}$ denote where 12 occurs, $A_{23}$ denote where 23 occurs, $A_{34}$ denote where 34 occurs, $A_{45}$ denote where 45 occurs, $A_{51}$ denote where 51 occurs. Also let $|U|=5!$ where there are no restrictions to the string. By gluing numbers together (i.e. 1245, 5123) and using inclusion/exclusion we get
>
> > $$\begin{aligned}
> > |A_{12}&\cup A_{23}\cup A_{34}\cup A_{45}\cup A_{51}|\\
> > &= |A_{12}|+|A_{23}|+|A_{34}|+|A_{45}|+|A_{51}|\\
> > &\qquad-(A_{12}A_{23}+A_{12}A_{34}+A_{12}A_{45}+A_{12}A_{51}+A_{23}A_{34}\\
> > &\qquad\qquad+A_{23}A_{45}+A_{23}A_{51}+A_{34}A_{45}+A_{34}A_{51}+A_{45}A_{51})\\
> > &\qquad+(A_{12}A_{23}A_{34}+\cdots+A_{34}A_{45}A_{51})\\
> > &\qquad-(A_{12}A_{23}A_{34}A_{45}+\cdots+A_{23}A_{34}A_{45}A_{51})\\
> > &\qquad+A_{12}A_{23}A_{34}A_{45}A_{51}\\
> > &=\ 5(4!)-10(3!)+10(2!)-5(1!)+0\\
> > &=\ 75 \end{aligned}$$
>
> Then $|U|-|A_{12}\cup A_{23}\cup A_{34}\cup A_{45}\cup A_{51}|=120-75=45$

Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good work! Your calculation is correct.

> The $\color{blue}{45}$ admissible strings are
>   \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
> 13254&13524&13542&14253&14325&14352&15243&15324&15432\\
> 21354&21435&21543&24135&24153&24315&25314&25413&25431\\
> 31425&31524&31542&32154&32415&32541&35214&35241&35421\\
> 41325&41352&41532&42135&42153&42531&43152&43215&43521\\
> 52143&52413&52431&53142&53214&53241&54132&54213&54321\\
> \end{array}

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for double checking and listing the strings.

Comment: @Nixie777: You're welcome! The strings are the output of a small snippet of R code which I've written to verify this and similar cases. In fact, most of the time needed was the pretty formatting stuff. :-)